# Trouble Loading an Image from an Amazon S3 Bucket (without using the URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pug

I have been following the advice of various users on this website and froom online tutorials but when I try to load an image from an S3 Amazon Bucket, the locally hosted screen only shows '[Object Object]' in place of the image. The credentials for the account are correct and I have been able to show images from the bucket when loading only the html for the image itself. However I am using a PUG template so perhaps I am missing something important to account for the added complexity.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "{{key}}",
    secretAccessKey: "{{key}}",
    defaultRegionName: 'eu-west-2'
});

let s3 = new AWS.S3();
this.image = s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'foodproducts',
    Key: 'SainsShroomdogs.jpg'
}, function (errtxt, file) {
    if (errtxt) {
        console.Log("lireFic", "ERR " + errtxt);
    } else {
        console.log('lecture OK')
        this.image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + encode(file.Body);

    }
});

function encode(data) {
    var str = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + String.fromCharCode(b)
    }, '');
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g, '$&\n');
}

res.render('index', {
    productName: this.name,
    productDescription: this.description,
    imageTest: this.image
});
```

});
[image: Locally hosted page]

Here is the .pug file code:

```
    doctype html
head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  title Internet Food Database
  style
    include ./SearchPageStylesheet.css

.container
  .top
    p  Top
  .middle
    .left
      p  Left
    .centre
      .productImage

      .productTitleText
        h1= productName
        p=  productDescription
        imageTest= imageTest
    .right
      p  Right
  .bottom
    p  Bottom
```

How do I retrieve the image from the private S3 amazon bucket and then store it inside this.image, ready for showing on the locally hosted html page?

Comment: What is the contents of the `imageTest` object? Have you tried logging it to the console? The path or data you need may be a property of the object that is being returned.

Comment: i have logged it and it appears to be the request to amazon in Object form. Request {
    body: '',
     endpoint:
      Endpoint {
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'foodproducts.s3.amazonaws.com',
        port: 443,
        hostname: 'foodproducts.s3.amazonaws.com',
        pathname: '/',
        path: '/',
      
        _header:
         'GET /SainsShroomdogs.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws-sdk-nodejs/2.677.0 darwin/v10.16.2 callback\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nHost: foodproducts.s3.amazonaws.com\r\nX-Amz-Content-Sha256: ...

Comment: Could this need encoding in order to be shown on the page? I have tried using the 'encode' function shown above (as used in tutorials) but 'data.reduce' nor 'btoa' is recognised as a function so this fails to execute

Comment: Try replacing `imageTest= imageTest` with `img(src= imageTest.src)`

Comment: Error: 
    18|         h1= productName
    19|         p=  productDescription
  > 20|         imageTest= img(src= imageTest.src)


img is not a function

Comment: No, line 20 should be `img(src= imageTest.src)` not `imageTest= img(src= imageTest.src) `

Comment: Sorry that makes more sense, unfortunately although there is no error, the image does not load so there is just empty space